# My MapsActivity crashes without any error message

Tags: performance, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I think that the problem is I don't know to use well the Coroutines. In Maps Activity you'll see that I access to a PointsDao suspend function that returns a List of objects that I want to use to create marks at my Google Maps Activity.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
```

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding
private lateinit var requestPermissionLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>
private val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private val mapsViewModel: MapsViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
    ) {
        permissions ->
            if (permissions.getOrDefault(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false)) {
                Log.d("fine_location", "Permission granted")
            } else {
                Log.d("fine_location", "Permission not granted")
                getBackToMainActivity()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Necessites acceptar els permisos de geolocalització per a realitzar la ruta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            if (permissions.getOrDefault(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, false)) {
                Log.d("coarse_location", "Permission granted")
            } else {
                Log.d("coarse_location", "Permission not granted")
                getBackToMainActivity()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Necessites acceptar els permisos de geolocalització per a realitzar la ruta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    requestLocationPermissions()
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera.
 */
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        val listOfPoints = getRoutePoints()
        for (point in listOfPoints) {
            mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(LatLng( point.latitude, point.longitude)))
            if (point == listOfPoints[0]) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude), 18f))
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun requestLocationPermissions() {
    when (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) -> {
            Log.d("fine_location", "Permission already granted")
        }
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) -> {
            Log.d("coarse_location", "Permission already granted")
        }
        else -> {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(permissions)
        }
    }
}

private fun getBackToMainActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

private fun getRouteId(): Int {
    return intent.getIntExtra("routeId", 0)
}

// Gets the points from room repository through ViewModel
private fun getRoutePoints(): List<PointOfInterest> {
    val route = getRouteId()
    var points = emptyList<PointOfInterest>()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        points = mapsViewModel.getRoutePoints(route)
    }
    return points
}
```

This is my ViewModel for this Activity:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MapsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: RoomRepository): ViewModel() {

    suspend fun getRoutePoints(routeId: Int): List<PointOfInterest> {
        return repository.getPointsByRouteId(routeId)
    }
}
```

And the Dao:

```
@Dao
interface PointsDao
{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM points_tbl WHERE route_id = :routeId")
    suspend fun getRoutePoints(routeId: Int): List<PointOfInterest>
}
```

My stracktrace error:

```
Process: com.buigues.ortola.touristics, PID: 27515
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.enforceMainThreadIfNeeded(LifecycleRegistry.java:317)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:172)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.attachToLifecycle(SavedStateHandleController.java:49)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.create(SavedStateHandleController.java:70)
        at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:67)
        at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:84)
        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:109)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:171)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:139)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:44)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:31)
        at com.buigues.ortola.touristics.ui.MapsActivity.getMapsViewModel(MapsActivity.kt:39)
        at com.buigues.ortola.touristics.ui.MapsActivity.getRoutePoints(MapsActivity.kt:123)
        at com.buigues.ortola.touristics.ui.MapsActivity.access$getRoutePoints(MapsActivity.kt:31)
        at com.buigues.ortola.touristics.ui.MapsActivity$onMapReady$1.invokeSuspend(MapsActivity.kt:85)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

Comment: There is always an error message. Your LogCat might have a filter turned on. Also, you cannot convert a suspend function to return something in a non-suspend function like that (but that wouldn't cause a crash). You're returning your empty list from `getRoutePoints()`. See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68370029/506796

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04 I will write in another message here my stacktrace error. If you could help me to understand it I would be pleased

Comment: I'm using Hilt with the @AndroidEntryPoint for the activity, but I think the problem is on the use of coroutines and suspend, I've not found any video with simple but concise explanations about this. Apparently the illegal state error is when you are doing "something" in the wrong place ("erroneus thread ??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here in `getRoutePoints()`.

```
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        points = mapsViewModel.getRoutePoints(route)
    }
```

The `by viewModels()` in your ViewModel property does a lazy load of the ViewModel. As a result, if you access your ViewModel property for the first time when you are not on the main thread, it will try to create it on the wrong thread, triggering this crash. ViewModels must be constructed on the main thread.

`CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)` means you are creating a coroutine scope that by default uses background IO threads, so this code is run on a background thread.

You should not be creating a CoroutineScope for this anyway, because your Activity already has one that is properly managed by the Activity lifecycle (so it will cancel any in-progress jobs if the activity is closed, to avoid wasting resources).

Also, `getRoutePoints()` is a suspend function. There's no reason for you to be using `Dispatchers.IO` here. A suspend function by convention is safe to call from any dispatcher. (It is however possible to write one that breaks convention, but Room is properly designed and does not break convention.)

To fix the crash and run a coroutine properly, you should use `lifecycleScope.launch { //...`. However, this function as you have designed it won't do what you expect. It launches a coroutine to retrieve a value, but then it immediately returns before that coroutine has finished running, so in this case will just return the initial `emptyList()`. When you launch a coroutine, you are queuing up background work, but the current function that called launch continues synchronously without waiting for the coroutine results. If it did, it would be a blocking function. There's more information about that in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68370029/506796).

So, you should instead make this a suspend function:

```
// Gets the points from room repository through ViewModel
private suspend fun getRoutePoints(): List<PointOfInterest> {
    val route = getRouteId()
    return mapsViewModel.getRoutePoints(route)
}
```

And your `onMapReady` function should also be fixed to use proper scope:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val listOfPoints = getRoutePoints()
        for (point in listOfPoints) {
            mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(LatLng( point.latitude, point.longitude)))
            if (point == listOfPoints[0]) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude), 18f))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Men I will try, thanks for your explanation, I will try this week to focus in learning well about coroutines and suspend functions, because I don't know if I understand well these concepts. Do you know someone in Youtube that could explain this well and simple?

Comment: And by addition, if you could help me... why an app crashes by this? It appears when starting Google Maps Activity 

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.buigues.ortola.touristics:layout/activity_maps: Binary XML file line #8 in com.buigues.ortola.touristics:layout/activity_maps: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.buigues.ortola.touristics:layout/activity_maps: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: I’m not familiar with any YouTube tutorials. My way of learning is reading official documentation and source code of the standard library and open source apps. With the limited stack trace you provided there is apparently a mistake in that XML file on the line it’s telling you.